# error processing your request SQLSTATE[42S22

Tags: magento

Hello can anyone please help me with the following error I'm getting within magento

> There has been an error processing your request SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) -
>   IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) -
>   IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) -
>   (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(ma' in 'field
>   list', query was: SELECT `SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced,
>   0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) -
>   IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) -
>   (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) -
>   IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) -
>   IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) *
>   main_table`.`base_to_global_rate)` AS `lifetime`,
>   `AVG((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) -
>   IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) -
>   IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) -
>   (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) -
>   IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) -
>   IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) *
>   main_table`.`base_to_global_rate)` AS `average` FROM
>   `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.status NOT
>   IN('canceled')) AND (main_table.state NOT IN('new',
>   'pending_payment'))

Trace:

```
# 0 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(65540): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(54759): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(55796): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#4 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(56732): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#5 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(55016): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#6 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(32374): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#7 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(33000): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#8 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(32206): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Sales.php(65): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(1987): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Sales->_prepareLayout()
#11 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28503): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#12 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard.php(54): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
#13 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(1987): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
#14 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28503): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#15 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28519): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#16 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28286): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#17 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout.php(40): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28252): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#19 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#20 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28257): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#21 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#22 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14198): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks()
#23 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14123): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#24 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#25 /home/harrison/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#26 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14272): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#27 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18736): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#28 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18266): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21117): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /home/harrison/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /home/harrison/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('base', 'website')
#32 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable compilation or recompile files.

Answer (score 0):

Fault was due to an incomplete upgrade. 
I had tried to upgrade to 1.9.2.2 but realised my skin didnt support it. So reuploaded the 1.9.2.1 files and all seemed to work. 
However during the 1.9.2.2 upgrade, it creates extra sql entries that the 1.9.2.1 files dont have associations for.

Fix is to fully upgrade to 1.9.2.2